# Cannot able to load different html on div tag in a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some doubt, I'm having select option and on that select option I'm having different options
when I click on that it will load that HTML file and it works well for two options but for third option its
not working good, while clicking on the second option it gives an error like 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is' of undefined"

Here this is my code

```js
$(function() {
  $('#type').change(function() {
    if ($('#type').val() == 'a') {
      
        $('#loadCheckHere').load('./templates/a.html');
      }
    } else if ($('#type').val() == 'b') {
 
        $('#loadCheckHere').load('./templates/b.html');
      
    } else {
      alert('select properly');
      $('#loadCheckHere').load('./templates/c.html');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="type" id="type" style="margin-left:57px;width:180px;">
 <option name="" value="">Select Asset Recovery</option>
 <option name="a" value="a">Add A</option>
 <option name="b" value="b">Add B</option>
 <option name="c" value="c">Add C</option>
</select>

<!--This is div tag,Here only I'm loading different html-->
<div id="loadCheckHere" style="background-color:white"></div>
```

Comment: Where are $('#a') and $('#b') ? I don't see any elements with those id in your code

Comment: @Aria In this case it should be `$('option[name=a]')` and `$('option[name=b]')`. I feel the undefined error on `.is()` only come from this.

Comment: @Plotisateur +1 beause of your solution, Yes there is no element with id `a` or `b` it should be `<option id="a" value="a">Add Printer</option>` or use your suggestion.

Comment: @Ashika, why you want check visibility of option `a` or `b`, do you want to load `a.html` or `b.html` just by selecting related option  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a plunker, check it out

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/LvfakcByxqAbLQxIGNzQ?p=info)

Things looks fine for me

```
$(function() {
  $('#type').change(function() {
    if ($('#type').val() == 'a') {

      $('#loadCheckHere').load('a.html');

    } else if ($('#type').val() == 'b') {

      $('#loadCheckHere').load('b.html');

    } else {
      //alert('select properly');
      $('#loadCheckHere').load('c.html');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. But I'm using Kendo UI framework so I'm trying to use it on that page that's why it throwing that error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one of your values, with a property key of 'is' is undefined.

Candidates are:

```
var isPrinterVisible = $('#a').is(':visible');
```

and

```
var isPcVisible = $('#b').is(':visible');
```

Are you sure an element with an id of "a" or "b" exists on the page? In order words, what do you get when you type `$('#a')` or `$('#b')` in the web console?

Based on the HTML provided, it seems that the options you provided have only name and value attributes set, however no id.

Maybe we can try to change:

```
 <option name="a" value="a">Add Printer</option>
 <option name="b" value="b">Add PC</option>
 <option name="c" value="c">Store Deinstall</option>
```

to:

```
<option id="a" name="a" value="a">Add Printer</option>
<option id="b" name="b" value="b">Add PC</option>
<option id="c" name="c" value="c">Store Deinstall</option>
```

Comment: My question is to can we change or load different HTML on the single page?

Comment: @Ashika it looks like you have already solved your problem! Remember to upvote if you found my response helpful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Option B is not an ID/#. It’s written as value=b which causes it undefined. The syntax is probably causing it to be an error

Comment: @Ashika which framework are you using for this edited one?

Comment: My code is working properly but I'm using Kendo UI framework so, In that framework, I need to create a separate HTML page and need to access it.I have tried this on jquery code is working but I can't able to do it.It keeps on throwing an error when I try to move on to other pages.